# Datagridview Flickers on changing combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, cell-formatting

I am updating the cell format depending on the choice of combobox as soon as i choose value in combobox the cells where i want to change the format it starts flickering as shown in the video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_9h8HQFigeDiVkjDVvIcul_yOmyJHq_c/view?usp=sharing)

Here's the cell formating code:

```
private void dg_PDetails_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbo_PurchaseCurrency.Text == "Rupees Purchase")
        {
            var format = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
            format.CurrencySymbol = "₹ ";
            dg_PDetails.Columns["AmountProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = format;
            dg_PDetails.Columns["AmountProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
            dg_PDetails.Columns["RateProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = format;
            dg_PDetails.Columns["RateProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
        }
        else if (cbo_PurchaseCurrency.Text == "Dollar Purchase")
        {
            var formats = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
            formats.CurrencySymbol = "$ ";
            dg_PDetails.Columns["AmountProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = formats;
            dg_PDetails.Columns["AmountProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
            dg_PDetails.Columns["RateProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = formats;
            dg_PDetails.Columns["RateProduct"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
        }
        String value = e.Value as string;
        if ((value != null) && value.Equals(e.CellStyle.DataSourceNullValue))
        {
            e.Value = e.CellStyle.NullValue;
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you may be using the wrong event for this. The `DataGridView’s` `CellFormatting` event gets fired often, like when the user moves the cursor over a cell. This means that the cells are getting formatted when it is not necessary and possibly causing the flicker you are seeing. If you want this format changed “when” the combo box changes, then you should put the code into one of the “combo boxes” value changed or selected value/index changed events. It is unnecessary to format the grid unless the combo box value changes.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks for the help works perfectly now